# how to change the type of constraint's arguments in ortools

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I don't know my question is possible or not. I am using ortools to solve an optimization problem and I know in the part of conditions the argument should be defined in double type, like this:

```
constraints[i] = solver.Constraint(0.0 , 10,0)
```

But my problem is that, I don't want to use this type of argument in creating conditions. For example I want to have a list.

So I wrote this in my code:

```
constraints[i] = solver.Constraint([1,2,3,...])
```

And I got this error:

```
return _pywraplp.Solver_Constraint(self, *args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded 
function 'Solver_Constraint'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
operations_research::MPSolver::MakeRowConstraint(double,double)
operations_research::MPSolver::MakeRowConstraint()
operations_research::MPSolver::MakeRowConstraint(double,double,std::string 
const &)
operations_research::MPSolver::MakeRowConstraint(std::string const &)
```

Is there any way to change the type of condition's argument?

Comment: I'd appreciate a clarification on your higher-level goal here.

I understand that if you write `constraint = solver.Constraint(0.0 , 10.0)`, it means something like, "I am going to make an expression called `constraint`, and the value of the expression should be constrained to the bounds [0, 10]".

If you write `constraint = solver.Constraint([1,2,3,...])`, what would you want that to mean?

Comment: @CrepeGoat, As you said `constraint = solver.Constraint(0.0 , 10.0)` means that you have an expression called `constraint` and the value of the expression should be a bound between 0 to 10. but I don't want to constrain the value of expression to Integer bound, actually as my expression is sum of some lists, so I want to constrain it to a list. And also not a bound, exactly a list.

Answer (score 0):

## My Assumptions

- your constraint expression is "a sum of some lists", meaning something along the lines of what [the NumPy library](http://www.numpy.org/) does: e.g., if you have two lists of values, `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]`, their sum would be *element-wise*, s.t. `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` = `[1+4, 2+5, 3+6]` = `[5, 7, 9]`.
- your "list constraint" is also element-wise; e.g., `[x1, x2, x3] <= [1, 2, 3]` means `x1 <= 1`, `x2 <= 2` and `x3 <= 3`.
- you're using the [GLOP Linear Solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop). (Everything I say below applies to the ILP/CP/CP-SAT solvers, but some of the particular method names/other details are different.)

## My Answer

The thing is, `ortools` only lets you set *scalar* values (like numbers) as variables; you can't make a "list variable", so to speak.

Therefore, you'll have to make a **list of scalar variables** that effectively represents the same thing.

For example, let's say you wanted your "list variable" to be a list of values, each one subjected to a particular constraint which you have stored in a list. Let's say you have a list of upper bounds:

```
upper_bounds = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
```

And you have several lists of solver variables like so:

```
vars1 = [
    # variable bounds here are chosen arbitrarily; set them to your purposes
    solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity, 'x{0}'.format(i))
    for i in range(n)
]
vars2 = [...]  # you define any other variable lists in the same way
```

Then, you would make a list of constraint objects, one constraint for each upper bound in your list:

```
constraints = [
    solver.Constraint(0, ubound)
    for ubound in upper_bounds
]
```

And you insert the variables into your constraints however is dictated for your problem:

```
# Example expression: X1 - X2 + 0.5*X3 < UBOUND
for i in range(n):
    constraints[i].SetCoefficient(vars1[i], 1)
    constraints[i].SetCoefficient(vars2[i], -1)
    constraints[i].SetCoefficient(vars3[i], 0.5)
```

Hope this helps! I recommend taking (another, if you already have) look at the examples for your particular solver. The one for GLOP can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop).